# CUDA : vectors addition and vectors size

Tags: vector, cuda

I measured the bandwidth when executing a kernel doing an addition between two vectors :

```
__global__ void add(float *a, float *b, float *c, int n)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    while (tid < n)
    {
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b [tid];
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}
```

I firstly launch the kernel once, so that it is loaded on the device, and next, I measure 10 iterations of the kernel execution.

The bandwidth is by far better when my vectors'length is 1000000 than 1000.

Why ?

Thanks.

Comment: The GPU can hide memory latency when it has more work to do.

Answer (score 5):

GPUs have very high memory bandwidth (good) *and* very high memory latency (bad).  It takes several hundred cycles for a memory request to be satisfied, but there can be many in-flight requests that are pipelined.

If you're only adding a 1000 elements, what you're really measuring is memory latency.

With much larger vectors, there will be enough thread blocks that when one is stalled on memory, the GPU can switch to another thread block whose memory request is done being satisified.  With them, you're measuring bandwidth.

Comment: But from what I read, the data should be read by blocks of 128 bytes (warps, coalescing...). If so, there should be a latence for each block, and as I am comparing 1000 and 1000000 elements, the difference should be linear, no ?<br/>

There would be a difference if the data were read once in the two cases. Than I'd understand why the latency is relatively more important with 1000 elemnts.

Comment: It's not linear due to pipelining.  Suppose each block reads 128 bytes and it takes 300 cycles of latency for a memory request.  Suppose you have 300 blocks.  On clock tick 0, the first block makes a memory request that will be satisfied by clock tick 300.  On clock tick 1, another block executes (context switches are free on GPUs), and it'll stall till tick 301.  The last block will issue its memory request at tick 299 and it'll be satisfied at tick 599.  Thus all 300 blocks will finish in 600 cycles total, not 300*300=90,000.  The actual latency is dependent on your particular card.